# Proper usage of XML inline documentation for derived classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, xml-documentation

While I think I understand why inline XML documentation (i.e. using three slashes - ///) isn't working for me, I'd like to get some guidance on how to work around my "problem".

I have an interface, and two derived classes.  One derived class is for simulation, and the other is for talking to real hardware.

It's very likely that the hardware implementation would do something special that the simulator doesn't need to do.  I have XML documentation for the hardware methods, and not for the simulator.  However, when I hover over the method name, I don't get documentation in the tooltip at all, presumably because the XML docs aren't associated with the interface.

This certainly makes sense, and I plan to just put my documentation in the interface instead and live with it.  I am still curious, though... how does everyone else do this?  Is there some magical way to make the tooltip aggregate all of the valid XML docs?  In other words, since the compiler doesn't know which derived class is being used, is there a way for it to show XML docs for all classes that implement this interface?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are programming to an interface, there is not a way to pass through the XML documentation from the implementation.  The separation means that the two "sides" don't know about each other.  Like you said, you could have two different implementations of that interface.  In that case, you would have a conflict.  That isn't a big deal for two, but what about 200?  Besides, the point of using an interface is that you don't care how it is implemented.  You know that when you call use an interface, the implementation will follow the contract.  Use the XML comments on the interface to describe the contract, not the implementation of the contract.

I can feel your pain on this one and I'm not sure that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This won't solve all your problems but [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) can quickly insert documentation into a derived class using the base class documentation. It's worth taking a look anyway if you're doing XML documentation.